# Background image outside of box on horizontal li items

Tags: css, background-image, horizontallist

I understand that background images cannot go outside the box of an element. However, this is my case:

I have a horizontal list where each list item should have a hover effect where a little arraw sits atop the item. Just positioning the background won't work as the list items are just as high as the text. Anything positioned outside the box gets cut off.

I read about a solution with an additional element within each list item that just holds the image.

Is there a way to simply change the height of the list item e.g. making the box higher so that the background image would stay within the box?

Comment: can you show some code/fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this the answer you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/G5VVj/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{height: 50px; width:30px; margin:0 10px; float:left; list-style:none;}
li:hover{background: url('http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/web_icons/gray-bold-up-arrow-icon.png') top center no-repeat;}
a{padding:20px 0; display:block;}
```

The strategy is to have an element within an element and give the parent element a `:hover` pseudo class that changes the background when hovered.